# How to convert std::string to std::vector<uint8_t>?

Tags: c++, c++11

The data format required to save games on google play game services is : `std::vector<uint8_t>` as specified under 'Data formats' on:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/savedgames

I am assuming the vector represents some kind of byte array. Is that correct ? So how does one convert an `std::string` to `std::vector<uint8_t>` ?

Comment: If you want to do it char-by-char, you could loop and cast/add elements to a vector...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`std::vector` has a constructor just for this purpose:

```
std::string str;
std::vector<uint8_t> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: Possible signed/unsigned conversion error/warning? Other than that, spot on.

Comment: Don't you need to add `'\0'` if you want the whole content of a string ?

Comment: @pSoLT- No. The NUL terminator is considered part of the string. `end` points one past it.

Comment: @pSoLT: the terminating zero is part of the C-style string convention, not part of the C++ string and normally `std::vector<uint8_t>`should not be considered a string.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I disagree (see previous comment)

Comment: @stefaanv - In the current standard, the `data` member must return a NUL terminated string. Ergo, `end` points one past it.

Comment: Can you convert back to a string as well ?

Comment: @stefaanv I guess the whole point is to store it byte-wise. Without null terminator, how do you distinguish the strings after reading if from file (assuming there can be many) ?

Comment: Nope, I just did the test in [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec0c8286510593bd)

Comment: @stefaanv But if we need to convert back to a string, shouldn't we store the  \0 as well ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to do it yourself.  Or store the size before.

Comment: @StoryTeller Nope, `std::string`'s storage has an additional null byte at the end, but it's not part of the string proper.

Comment: @T.C. - Yes, I stand corrected. The [reference for `data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) confirms it.

Comment: Is this also working for std::vector<double> vec(str.begin(), str.end()); ?? What would be a correct input for str?

Comment: @sqp_125 It would assign a bunch of doubles with ASCII values. Same as `double a = 98; \\ 'b'`

Comment: Yeah true.... and how to convert these values than back to the originall double values?

Answer (score 12):

Adding to DeiDei's answer, you can do the following if the vector is already constructed:

```
std::string str;
std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
...
vec.assign(str.begin(), str.end());
```